# Python pandas or lambda utility to filter data from dataset

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have updated the question with the functionality. I need to use the dataset below and and modify rollup columns and snapshot_interval based on the uuid present in azid.

Input

```
uuid    azid                    Rollup   Snapshot_Interval
ce2354  ['fe4578'; 'ce2354']    [1;1]   ['MONTHLY';'WEEKLY']
ca8458  ['de9874'; 'ca8458']    [7;6]   ['WEEKLY';'DAILY']
be4589  ['be4589';'we6780']     [4;6]   ['YEARLY','WEEKLY']
```

Output Table:

```
uuid    azid                 Rollup  Snapshot_Interval
ce2354  ['fe4578'; 'ce2354']    1       MONTHLY
ca8458  ['de9874'; 'ca8458']    7       WEEKLY
be4589  ['be4589';'we6780']     6       WEEKLY
```

Condition: 1. Comparing uuid with azid with Lambda. If uuid is in second part of azid then the correct values of columns rollup and snapshot_interval are the first element of record available in the lists of rollup and snapshot_interval columns respectively.
2. If uuid is in first part of azid then the correct values are second element of record available in the lists of rollup and snapshot_interval columns respectively.

Explanation:

1. uuid 'ce2354' is available in second part of azid ['fe4578'; 'ce2354']  and so Rollup and Snapshot_Intervals to be displayed must be 1, MONTHLY. These are available in the first part of the list.
2. uuid 'be4589' is available in first part of azid ['be4589';'we6780'] and so Rollup and Snapshot_Intervals to be displayed must be 6, WEEKLY. These are available in second part of the list.

I tried writing the code below using pandas and Lambda but I am seeing some errors. Any updated methods in python will help.

```
df1= d1['Rollup'].str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False)
df2_updated = df2.loc[(df['uuid']==df['azid']), df2['Rollup'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z ]+)',expand=False)]
```

Comment: please provide your datasets (input/output) as text

Comment: I have updated the datasets as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `azid` must contain `uuid`, `azid` are just 2-element lists, I think here is a simple solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"uuid": ['ce2354', 'ca8458', 'be4589'],
               "azid": [['fe4578', 'ce2354'], ['de9874', 'ca8458'], ['be4589', 'we6780']],
               "Rollup": [[1,1], [7,6], [4,6]],
               "Snapshot_Interval": [['MONTHLY','WEEKLY'], ['WEEKLY','DAILY'], ['YEARLY','WEEKLY']]})

def find_index(uuid, azid):
    if (str(uuid) == str(azid[0])):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.Rollup[i] = df.Rollup[i][find_index(df.uuid[i], df.azid[i])]
    df.Snapshot_Interval[i] = df.Snapshot_Interval[i][find_index(df.uuid[i], df.azid[i])]
```

Comment: I analyzed and ran the code. First two records are populated correctly, however for the third record - Rollup and snapshot_interval appears incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo mistake as the third row at `uuid`, 'be4589' not 'be4859'. the code is still good then. Btw I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Do you also have any other method to accomplish the same results? Using Lambda or any other packages?

Comment: I think using `lambda` is just another syntax. There no difference in algorithm, the important thing is you have to find the correct index for `Rollup` and `Snapshot_Interval`. I will post an answer using lambda in case you need.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Lambda:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"uuid": ['ce2354', 'ca8458', 'be4589'],
               "azid": [['fe4578', 'ce2354'], ['de9874', 'ca8458'], ['be4589', 'we6780']],
               "Rollup": [[1,1], [7,6], [4,6]],
               "Snapshot_Interval": [['MONTHLY','WEEKLY'], ['WEEKLY','DAILY'], ['YEARLY','WEEKLY']]})

def find_index(uuid, azid):
    if (str(uuid) == str(azid[0])):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0    

df.Rollup = df.Rollup.apply(lambda x: x[find_index(df.uuid[df.Rollup.to_list().index(x)], df.azid[df.Rollup.to_list().index(x)])])
df.Snapshot_Interval = df.Snapshot_Interval.apply(lambda x: x[find_index(df.uuid[df.Snapshot_Interval.to_list().index(x)], df.azid[df.Snapshot_Interval.to_list().index(x)])])
```